# Запуск php скрипта в фоновом режиме из другого php скрипта

Tags: php

Доброго времени! Задумал я тут одну задумку но не до конца понял как ее решить, задача такова - на странице есть php скрипт который заносит данные в базу данных а после успешной записи он должен сделать не большую рассылку по почте, процесс этот может быть долгим и я хочу сделать так что бы этот скрипт выполнялся в отдельном файле, что бы первый скрипт производил свою работы с базой данных и в случае успеха отправлял запрос на тут отдельную страницу php. Примерно так же как это делается через ajax подскажите можно ли это как то реализовтаь? или отправить xml запрос в тот скрипт что бы он начал рабоать?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить требуемый php-скрипт отдельным процессом. Пример [на eng SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process).

Comment: @aleks.andr вы имете в виду через exec ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без exec, pcntl_exec и.т.п. (они зачастую заблокированы и небезопасны). Можно дёрнуть нужный скрипт курлом, не дожидаясь ответа, пример:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

/*Опции запроса, чтобы не дожидаться ответа*/
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

/*Если используется HTTPAUTH*/
if( !empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && !empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ) {
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . ':' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
}

/*Код можно прикрепить, чтобы при обработке проверить подлинность запроса*/
if( $code ) {
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'curl_code=' . $code);
}

/*Выполняем*/
curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

На стороне обработчика запроса должно быть:

```
ignore_user_abort();
```

Таким образом и для пользователя невидимо - что он инициировал запрос, и это не приводит к "оттормаживанию" загрузки его страницы.

Answer (score 0):

После успешной записи в БД обычным get запросом обратитесь к php файлу на сервере, который будет рассылать.